# how to export workflow template in sharepoint designer 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, export, workflow-designer, workflow-template

We have one test site in my environment workflows is deployed in that site and those workflows are saved as "Save As Template". We want to add those save as template to another site.

Give me solutions..

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps for use Workflow Template in another site.

- Add workflow template in Solution galleries under site settings
- Feature added in site and activate feature
- Go to List/Library and add workflow
- Choose your workflow from list and it will add in list/library

Comment: ok. can you please make answer as right?